# how can I regroup multiple categorical variables into a new variable

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (df) with 2 columns (A, B):

```
   A    B
1  a TCRB
2  a TCRG
3  a TCRB
4  b TCRB
5  b TCRG
6  c TCRB
7  c TCRB
8  c TCRB
9  c TCRB
10 d TCRG
11 d TCRG
12 d TCRG
```

I want to create a new column "C" as bellow that tells me whether each unique variable in "A" has both TCRB and TCRG or either one of them (0= TCRB only, 1= TCRG only, 2= both) as follows:

```
A: a b c d 
C: 2 2 0 1
```

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(C = case_when("TCRB" %in% B & "TCRG" %in% B ~ 2,
                                 "TCRB" %in% B ~ 0,
                                 "TCRG" %in% B ~ 1,
                                 TRUE ~ NA_real_)) 
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  A         C
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a         2
2 b         2
3 c         0
4 d         1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ian for quick reply and also making the data more legible. I tried your code, got the error                                                                                                                     
 " no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character" any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps the column name is something other than `A` in your actual data? Also note that the column name should be unquoted. Also, be sure that you are piping the data in properly, you can do it all on one line `df %>% group_by(A)` Or you could also write it `group_by(df, A)`. You may also need to change `df` to whatever your data is called.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    summarise(C = n_distinct(B) *!all(B == 'TCRB'))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  A         C
#  <chr> <int>
#1 a         2
#2 b         2
#3 c         0
#4 d         1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "d", "d", "d"), B = c("TCRB", "TCRG", "TCRB", "TCRB", "TCRG", 
"TCRB", "TCRB", "TCRB", "TCRB", "TCRG", "TCRG", "TCRG")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much akrun, your method makes it really easy!

Answer (score 0):

In Base R, we can use `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(B~A, df, function(x) {
    if(all(c('TCRB', 'TCRG') %in% x)) 2
    else if(any(x == 'TCRG')) 1
    else if(any(x == 'TCRB')) 0
    else NA
})

#  A B
#1 a 2
#2 b 2
#3 c 0
#4 d 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ronak, I like your code, it's completely logical and easy to remember. For some reason it doesn't return anything when I use it. I'm replacing my actual column names and df obviously, otherwise not sure why it's not working, thoughts?

Comment: @medicine Did you assign the object back for changes to be visible? `df1 <- aggregate(B~A, df,.......` ?

Comment: it worked, I forgot to change x to my B vector, you can tell I'm really new to R! thanks again!